# Converting SQL Query to Linq Lambda statement

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to convert the the following SQL statement into a linq query but for some reason I cannot get it to work!!

```
SELECT     o.ITEMID, COUNT(o.ITEMID) AS COUNT, MAX(i.QUANTITY) AS Quantity
FROM       ORDERS AS o LEFT OUTER JOIN
           INVENTORY AS i ON o.ITEMID = i.ITEMID
           GROUP BY o.ITEMID
```

I found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/278ce79b-941b-44ea-8ca5-9ec4c3c3cafe/), somebody having a similar problem but I cant seem to apply this to what i need.

---

thanks for all your help.

This is the code i have so far

```
Dim castleavailability = _
            From o In orders _
            From i In inventorys _
            Where (x >= o.ITEMID = i.ITEMID)
            Group New With {o, i} By o.ITEMID Into oi()
            Select New With {.ItemId = oi.Key, .Count = oi.Select(y >= y.o.ItemId).Count(), .Quantity = oi.Select(y >= y.i.Quantity).Max()}
```

the error I am getting now is "Definition of method 'oi' is not accessible in this context." referring to the "group new with" line. Any ideas on how to resolve this

Many Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? And "it doesn't work" isn't an error description! Doesn't it compile? Does it throw a runtime exception? Does it run but return wrong results?

Comment: Is it Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Hi sorry it is linq to Entities. I didnt mean to click Linq to SQL

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you

```
var query = from o in context.Orders
            from i in context.Inventory
                             .Where(x = > o.ItemId = x.ItemId)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { o, i } by o.ItemId into oi
            select new
            {
              ItemId = oi.Key,
              Count = oi.Select(y => y.o.ItemId).Count(),
              Quantity = oi.Select(y => y.i.Quantity).Max(),
            };
```

Comment: Wow that was super fast thanks very much i will test this now.

Comment: Hi I am coding in vb so have changed this slightly to get rid of the errors showing in VS i have                                       

    Dim castleavailability = _
            From o In orders _
            From i In inventorys _
            Where (x >= o.ITEMID = x.ItemId) 
            group new { o, i } by o.ItemId into oi
            select new {ItemId = oi.Key, Count = oi.Select(y => y.o.ItemId).Count(), Quantity = oi.Select(y => y.i.Quantity).Max()}

I am getting the error Type or 'with' expected at 'group new {      '

Thanks

Comment: @user789433: Change every `new {` to `New With {` and add a dot in front of the left hand side of the inner expressions, e.g. `group New With { o, i }` and `select New With {.ItemId = oi.Key, .Count = ...`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc468406%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Linqer software to convert sql query to Linq Lambda query.

You can get this software from following link:

http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: I'm using Linqer but can't find any choice to translate SQL to Linq using Lambda expression, just classic Linq